# Trouble importing .sav into PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, spss

I have a SPSS file saved as a .sav that I am trying to migrate into a Postgres db. I tried using the SPSS export to database, but that does not seem to be working (still waiting to hear back from IBM). I also tried to export as a .csv and import it in via a GUI, Navicat, but the default data type is varchar(255) and can't detect the correct types. I can't sit down and create the tables manually as there are 640 variables.

Just as some other info there will be multiple of similar files going into multiple tables with around 250,000 tuples/table. If there is some sort of script that can automatically detect schema and let me export it or a software that does that or can accept .sav, willing to try pretty much anything.

Comment: Hmmm... What about [importing](http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html) `.sav` to R and then [exporting](https://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/) to PostgreSQL from R?

Comment: If you have access to the version of SPSS that created the .sav: dump as .csv and create an .sql import script for postgres and run that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem with the ODBC driver.  You might need a new one from the Data Access Pack or a native driver from the database vendor.